# How to save api response in usestate and pass it react player source

Tags: javascript, reactjs

API response :

```
Array(80)
0:
Camera_Number: "Camera_1"
Company_Name: "Fraction Analytics Limited"
Floor Number: "Ground_Floor"
Group_Name: "Group_1"
Video_Name: "http://localhost:4000/video/0"
[[Prototype]]: Object

1:
Camera_Number: "Camera_2"
Company_Name: "Fraction Analytics Limited"
Floor Number: "Ground_Floor"
Group_Name: "Group_1"
Video_Name: "http://localhost:4000/video/1"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Here `Video_Name: "http://localhost:4000/video/1"` these are react-hosted videos.

`App.js`

call API using fetch and print results on the console.

```
 const onGridReady = (params) => {
    console.log("grid is ready");
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/get_all")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.results);
        params.api.applyTransaction({ add: resp.results });
      });
  };
```

Now how to save API response in usestate and pass `Video_Name` field to react video player

```
    <iframe
      width="420"
      height="315"
      title="videos"
      src={"http://localhost:4000/video/0"}
      />
```

Here I just pass only one video to the source but I expected to pass multiple videos to the source dynamically.

[image]

When I click every time it should play different video as per api response

If you have any queries you can [refer here to code](https://github.com/iamharry-dev/modal_popup/blob/main/App.js)

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can just pass videos as array and select one by index, this index can be changed dynamically by calling

setState ({index_of_playing_video: video index })

```
<iframe
      width="420"
      height="315"
      title="videos"
      src={this.state.videos[this.state.index_of_playing_video]}
      />
```

Comment: nice, now just vote the answer above

Comment: can you please say how to pass the video to the source from API? now check I just added an image to my Github.

Comment: in actionButton the video params and the index, then use setState to put the index in the state, and it will rerender with the new video

Comment: can you please edit your answer , it will very useful for me and others

Comment: Ok, just share here the whole code

Comment: `https://github.com/iamharry-dev/modal_popup/blob/main/App.js` refer here for code. Thanks